# Wann verwendet man "bei" und wann "auf"

Tags: word-usage, preposition

Welches der Beispiele ist korrekt:

> Willkommen **bei** StackExchange

oder

> Willkommen **auf** StackExchange

Oder ist beides erlaubt?

**UPDATE**

Ich bin gerade dabei eine Website in 3 Sprachen zu übersetzen und bin da schon etwas verwirrt.

Ich denke, dass `Willkommen bei StackExchange` schon eher dazu passt, obwohl, wie [@Einer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/13560/3448) erörtert hat, *beides akzeptabel ist*, was der Grund meiner leichten Verwirrung ist.

Im Internet kann man **endlos viele** Beispiele finden, wie z.B:

> Willkommen **bei** Facebook...

**oder**

> Willkommen **auf** Facebook...

und zum Beispiel ([Original aus der Deutschen Facebook-Seite](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms))

> Dir gehören alle Inhalte und Informationen, die du **auf** Facebook postest.

**oder**

> ...wenn sie **bei** Facebook gepostet werden.

Das letzte Beispiel könnte man dann auch mit **auf** (um)schreiben:

> ...wenn sie **auf** Facebook gepostet werden.

Comment: Another possibility might be `Willkommen zur StackExchange`. Otherwise I would use `bei`. Cannot remember ever having seen `Willken auf..`.

Comment: I don't think `zu` would be a good fit here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Deutsch**

Normalerweise ist man *auf* einer Internet-Seite. Für eine Gruppe oder Organisation ist aber *bei* die richtige Präposition.

> Ich bin **bei** der Heilsarmee.

Und dann stellt sich die Frage, ob StackExchange eine Seite oder eher eine Gruppe ist, bzw. welcher Aspekt von SE gemeint ist. Sogesehen ist in diesem Fall beides akzeptabel.

**English**

Usually the right preposition for an internet-site would be *auf*. For a group or an organization *bei* would be right.

So the question would be, if StackExchange is a site or a community, resp. which aspect of SE you want to emphasize. So in this special case both prepositions would be acceptable.

Comment: Ich habe meine Frage aktualisiert um meine Verwirrung besser darzustellen. Deine Antwort ist gut (+1) aber bin noch nicht so ganz überzeugt, welche nun die richtige Präposition währe bzw. ob tatsächlich beide zulässig sind (in manchen Situationen).

Comment: @aldanux Die angeführte Unterscheidung ist ziemlich gut - könntest Du eine konkrete 'Situation' anführen? 'Bei' ist etwas persönlicher als 'auf'. Welche Präposition/Phrase wird im Originaltext verwendet?

Answer (score 3):

Ich stimme der [Antwort von Einer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/13560/) zu. Des Weiteren meine ich, dass man etwas **auf** Facebook postet, weil ja Facebook eine Webseite ist. Man registriert sich oder meldet sich aber **bei** Facebook an, weil man der Gruppe der Facebook-Nutzer beitritt bzw. weil anmelden die Präposition *bei* verlangt.

Willkommen **auf** Facebook – würde passen, wenn man die Facebook-Webseite aufruft, egal ob man Mitglied ist (und sich noch nicht angemeldet hat) oder nicht Mitglied ist.

Willkommen **bei** Facebook – würde passen, wenn man sich gerade angemeldet hat (oder wenn man gerade bei der Firma Facebook angestellt wurde).

Aber: Man bearbeitet etwas **auf** Wikipedia, weil man dadurch ja zum Mitarbeiter bei Wikipedia wird.

Ich hoffe, das hat nicht noch mehr Verwirrung gestiftet.

Comment: Ich sehe schon das es nicht so einfach ist... :) Aber das ergibt doch auch keinen wirklichen sinn, dass ich 2 texte schreiben muss.. einmal für die NICHT Mitglieder und einmal für die, die sich gerade angemeldet haben?? Google weiss nicht ob du bei Facebook angemeldet bist oder nicht, wenn du da eine suche startest... und da steht z.B. **bei** als Willkommen's Gruss... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ich möchte hier noch **zu** einwerfen, das schon in [Trilarions Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13559/wann-verwendet-man-bei-und-wann-auf#comment33417_13559) erwähnt wurde. Obwohl das beim gegebenen Beispiel nicht verwendet werden kann, ist es doch bei der Begrüßung zu Veranstaltungen zu finden.

> Wilkommen **zu** unserer 25-Jährigen Jubiläumsfeier.
>   Wilkommen **zur** (zu der) diesjährigen Comic-Con.

Zusätzlich noch:

**auf:** verwendet u.a. bei Schiffen, Zügen und Flügen:

> Wilkommen **auf** der MS Maria.
>   Wilkommen **auf** unserem Flug nach Costa Rica.
>   Wilkommen **auf** dem Inter City B2415 von Hamburg Altona nach Frankfurt.

Dort ist aber allgemein **an Bord** gebräuchlicher, das wiederum gebietet dann aber Genitiv ;)

Comment: Beim Intercity-Beispiel finde ich "Willkommen *im* Intercity auf der Fahrt von Hamburg Altona nach Frankfurt" natürlicher. Also *auf* dem Schiff, *im* Flugzeug, *in* der Bahn, aber *auf* der Fahrt, *auf* dem Flug.