# Auf oder am oder in? How to ask "are you on instagram/abc.com?"

Tags: preposition

Is it "Bist du am abc.com oder bist du auf abc.com"? 
Which is the right preposition?

Comment: "Auf"  is the right one . e.g 

Bist du auf Facebook ?  
Bücher, auf denen mein Name steht

Comment: @BahgatNassour Source?

Comment: Neither, it’s _bei_, but _auf_ kinda works, too.

Comment: @ Stephie „auf“ der Internetseite und „auf“ der Internetplattform. Eine mögliche Erklärung für die Präposition „auf“ ist, dass eine Internetseite und eine Internetplattform als zweidimensionale Fläche, Blog, Buch und Gedicht hingegen als etwas Abstraktes angesehen werden
http://www.sprachschach.de/welche-praeposition-passen/

Comment: Related: [What prepositions are appropriate with “Willkommen” and websites?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9506/9551), [Wann verwendet man “bei” und wann “auf”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/13559/9551), and [“Willkommen auf meinem Webauftritt” so korrekt?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20768/9551)

Comment: It depends.  What do you want to say?  *Do you have an X account?* vs *Are you logged into X right now?* vs *Are you visiting X right now?*  But *am* / *an* are wrong in any case.

Answer (score 3):

There's no fixed rule yet but referring to persons, the most common usages are "auf" and "bei", with a slight semantic difference. "Auf" is often used to mean "actively using", while "bei" just means "registered member" (or possibly "employee".)

Referring to content you could also use "in". ("Ich habe in Facebook gelesen, dass ...") Saying "Ich bin in Facebook" would be understood to refer to the fact that (some of) your personal data is stored there.

"Am" is unusual. I would consider it incorrect.

Comment: +1 for explaining the semantical difference of "auf" and "bei". -1 for the "in" stuff which is wrong.

Comment: I would never use "in". In your example, I would say "Ich habe auf Facebook gelesen...."

Answer (score -1):

"Auf", "bei" oder "in". Laut IdS-Korpora (Archiv W4) liegt z. B. für Facebook folgende Verteilung vor:

```
auf 12.003
bei  8.869
in   1.073
```

Hinsichtlich "bei" muss noch beachtet werden, dass man dies auch verwenden kann, um über die Firma an sich zu sprechen, etwa "bei Facebook gab es einen Personalwechsel"; auf den ersten Blick überwiegt "bei" im Sinne von "auf/in" jedoch deutlich.

Ich denke, es hängt mit der Frage zusammen, wie man eine Webseite wahrnimmt. Die meisten dürften eine Seite wahrnehmen als etwas, *auf* der etwas steht - vor ihren Augen.

Andere nehmen sie eher als einen Raum wahr, *in* dem sie sich befinden.
"Bei" wird vermutlich aus der Zugehörigkeit abgeleitet, so wie "Ich bin bei Daimler".

Edit: Hier noch zwei Belege für auf (es ist bei näherer Betrachtung jedoch geringer in der Zahl als oben angegeben):

> *Saale-Zeitung, 30.11.2011, S. 31; ohne Titel*
>   Scarlett Johansson hat keine Ambitionen, Privates von sich preiszugeben. "Ich bin weder auf Facebook noch auf Twitter. Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass ich etwas weniger gern tue als dauernd über Details aus meinem Alltag zu schreiben", sagt die Schauspielerin.

Oder:

> *Saale-Zeitung, 09.01.2012, S. 20; ohne Titel*
>   Webtrekk analysierte die Daten von mehr als 100 Millionen Internet-Nutzern. 32 Prozent der Senioren sind auf Facebook.

Da es schlicht keine Regel gibt und derzeit auch keine Regel geben kann, ist dies nicht falsch.

Comment: -1 weil der Eindruck entsteht, dass es egal sei, ob man "auf" oder "bei" verwendet

Comment: @falkb: Es *ist* egal. Die Präpositionen haben sich zu einer Zeit entwickelt, als es noch kein Facebook gab. Da man - räumlich - weder auf, in oder bei Facebook sein kann, weil Facebook nicht räumlich existiert, ist jeder Gebrauch eine Metapher, und welche Metapher man gebraucht, hängt von der eigenen Vorstellung ab. Irgendwann, wenn sich eine Präposition durchgesetzt haben sollte, kann man über eine Grammatikregel nachdenken.

Comment: @Veredomon: Das ist Quatsch. 'bei' heißt Mitglied, 'auf' heißt 'gerade in Benutzung', ganz klarer Fall

Comment: @SchcS: Habe noch zwei Belege geliefert.

Comment: +1 für nachvollziehbare und belegte Fakten statt persönlicher Meinung